# When defining external dependencies in meson, can you add search paths?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

When defining a target in meson, you can declare dependencies on external projects using the following syntax:

```
zdep = dependency('zlib', version : '>=1.2.8')
exe = executable('zlibprog', 'prog.c', dependencies : zdep)
```

This checks the standard include locations, which works well on Linux, but not so well on other platforms.

Is there a way to add additional include and library paths for meson to check when declaring dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation says: `dependency()` "*Finds an external dependency [...] with `pkg-config` if possible and with [library-specific fallback detection logic](http://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html) otherwise.*"

So, if you mean to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, you can do that as usual:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/wherever/your/installed/dir/is/
$ meson ....
```

Or, you can use back-end specific variables, ie. BOOST_ROOT.  [Check the doc](http://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html) for more info.

If you ment to find other libraries not using `pkg-config`, you can add a `dirs` keyword argument to point to the directory your libraries are in.

Comment: Am I the only one seeing a flaw in Meson? If my dependency is part of my repository, like particular version of gtest I cannot hint that in the script. That renders the repo unusable under Windows. I know I can define my own dependency in a subproject... but it makes the whole stuff nonsense. Bizarre.

Comment: @MichałFita What exactly is your problem? `declare_dependency()` has an argument `version` if you need.

Comment: Can I redeclare the dependency to point at the code that's part of my repo (literally copied into)?

Comment: I just don't understand why you need to "re"-declare. Care to make a question?

Comment: How does one override this for a specific dep? This answer assume you want the same prefix for all dependencies.

Comment: If you do NOT want to use the default `pkg-config` search directory, use `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR`.  Meson uses pkg-config for dependency detection.  When you want to override that behavior, do so with pkg-config.  If you want to use other methods for dependency detection, specify `method`.  Ref https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#dependency-detection-method